# Advanced MySQLi query syntax

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a fairly complex mysqli insert statement to do, as I need to gather data from two other tables and also use some variables available to me in php all in one statement.

It's confusing me because of the order of the variables for the prepared statements. - I am only inserting four values, but in order to get the values for t1 and t2, I am referencing these three additional variables too in the bind_param statement.

I should be populating jobRoleID,companyID,departmentID,competenceID with $newJobRoleID,$newCompanyID,t1.id,t2.id

```
$addJobCompetencies = $con->prepare("
INSERT INTO jobRoleCompetencies (jobRoleID,companyID,departmentID,competenceID)
WITH t1 AS (SELECT id FROM departments WHERE companyID = ? AND department = ?), 
     t2 AS (SELECT id FROM competencies WHERE companyID = ?)
     SELECT ?,?,t1.id,t2.id FROM t1,t2");

if($addJobCompetencies) {
    $addJobCompetencies->bind_param('isiii', $newCompanyID,$row['department'],$newCompanyID,$newJobRoleID,$newCompanyID);
    $addJobCompetencies->execute();
} else {
    echo $con->error;   
}
$addJobCompetencies->free_result();
```

I am getting a syntax error but I'm not 100% sure why. Can anyone help?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0):

I haven't resolved the syntax issue with this query, but have got around it by simply combining the select statements to retrieve all the information I need in a single select statement...

SELECT ?,?,departments.id AS departmentID,competencies.id AS competencyID FROM departments,competencies... etc